# Why 11n WLAN disabled for iwlwifi in 15.04?

Tags: networking, 15.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have a laptop with Intel Centrino N-6300 wireless card.

Recently I found out that I can't connect to 11n-only wireless networks.

After some research, the reason is that in `iwlwifi.conf` the 11n mode is disabled:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

After removing the entry, the connection to my 11n network worked.

Can anybody tell me why this mode is still disabled by default? (we are living in 2015, 11n-support should be a no-brainer).